# Why does NTFS store files in contiguous but separate fragments?

Tags: windows, ntfs

I get seemingly contradictory info from contig on a file:

```
>contig -nobanner -a -v "C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\pp.big"
------------------------
Processing C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\pp.big:
Scanning file...
[Cluster] Runlength
  [0] 31272
  [31272] 20376
  [51648] 20652
  [72300] 19452
  [91752] 21269
  [113021] 20674
  [133695] 22565
  [156260] 6409
  [162669] 23291
  [185960] 230176
  [416136] 320942
File size: 3019070010 bytes
C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\pp.big is in 4 fragments
------------------------
Summary:
     Number of files processed:      1
     Number unsuccessfully procesed: 0
```

It lists 11 fragments but then it says that there are just 4 fragments/extents. fsutil file queryextents confirms that the first 8 extents are consecutive:

```
VCN: 0x0        Clusters: 0x7a28     LCN: 0x26cbe3c    LCN_end:0x26d3864
VCN: 0x7a28     Clusters: 0x4f98     LCN: 0x26d3864    LCN_end:0x26d87fc
VCN: 0xc9c0     Clusters: 0x50ac     LCN: 0x26d87fc    LCN_end:0x26dd8a8
VCN: 0x11a6c    Clusters: 0x4bfc     LCN: 0x26dd8a8    LCN_end:0x26e24a4
VCN: 0x16668    Clusters: 0x5315     LCN: 0x26e24a4    LCN_end:0x26e77b9
VCN: 0x1b97d    Clusters: 0x50c2     LCN: 0x26e77b9    LCN_end:0x26ec87b
VCN: 0x20a3f    Clusters: 0x5825     LCN: 0x26ec87b    LCN_end:0x26f20a0
VCN: 0x26264    Clusters: 0x1909     LCN: 0x26f20a0    LCN_end:0x26f39a9
VCN: 0x27b6d    Clusters: 0x5afb     LCN: 0x1f7fec9    LCN_end:0x1f859c4
VCN: 0x2d668    Clusters: 0x38320    LCN: 0x26f39a9    LCN_end:0x272bcc9
VCN: 0x65988    Clusters: 0x4e5ae    LCN: 0x2ca2da0    LCN_end:0x2cf134e
```

(I added the last column, computed from Clusters + LCN, which matches LCN in the next line for the first 8 lines)

Why does NTFS segment the first fragment/extent into 8 different, odd sized parts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What block allocation algorithm does NTFS use?](https://superuser.com/questions/274855/what-block-allocation-algorithm-does-ntfs-use)  "the NTFS filesystem attempts to allocate the file in contiguous storage. However it can only do that if the filesystem knows the size of the file."

Comment: @K7AAY not really. I'm not concerned that the file is not contiguous. Only four fragments is pretty good. What I don't get is why the first fragment is actually 8 separate allocations.

Comment: Because Microsoft didn't make sure if there were multiple consecutive fragments to make them one extent/

Comment: From my experience the fragmentation size mainly is determined by the application which writes the data. I once had a program that was writing all data in chunks of ~1,4KB  onto an NTFS drive without further buffering. NTFS took those continuously written chunks and directly saved each chunk as an own fragment. I only noticed this because it was a large file that in the end exceeded maximum fragmentation of a file...

Comment: @Robert What's puzzles me here it not that the file takes several fragments, but that the fragments are actually contiguous so could be a single fragment if only NTFS made it so. Maybe the question is unclear?

Comment: It depends on the default cluster size your file system is based on. NTFS chooses it based on the size of your disk. It's usually 4kb per cluster up to 16TB, up to 64kb for disks whose capacity range from 128TB to 256TB. That may be that when you (or the OEM who built your PC) formatted this drive, default cluser size was set to an arbitrary value of, say, 32kb per cluster. In that case, file fragmentation would be factored differently than if your drive was formatted to a default 4kb.

Comment: All above is out of topic. The problem is with "VCN:0x0 Clusters:0x7a28,...LCN_end:0x26d3864" followed by "VCN:0x7a28,LCN:0x26d3864..." which ARE ALREADY contiguous extents, but it use two records, that NTFS forgot to compact into just one (this is waste of space in the MFT entry, or can cause the table of extents to become non-resident, or cause other file attributes to become non-resident, i.e. not in the MFT). Apparently the NTFS.sys driver forgets to compact this table (even when using DEFRAG or CONTIG) for unknown reason.

Comment: The solution for this is to use "FSUTIL FILE OPTIMIZEMETADATA" (this may sometimes restore some attributes back into the MFT entry, making them resident, and thus unallocating some clusters for non-resident attributes, and can allow a NTFS volume to be reduced (it may be blocked if some non-resident attributes, such as ACLs, are protected)

Answer (score 3):

This is a matter of terminology.

The Microsoft article
[Clusters and Extents](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/clusters-and-extents)
defines these terms:

> **Clusters** may be referred to from two different perspectives: within the file and on the volume. Any cluster in a file has a virtual
>   cluster number (VCN), which is its relative offset from the beginning
>   of the file. For example, a seek to twice the size of a cluster,
>   followed by a read, will return data beginning at the third VCN. A
>   logical cluster number (LCN) describes the offset of a cluster from
>   some arbitrary point within the volume. LCNs should be treated only as
>   ordinal, or relative, numbers. There is no guaranteed mapping of
>   logical clusters to physical hard disk drive sectors.
>
> An **extent** is a run of contiguous clusters. For example, suppose a
>   file consisting of 30 clusters is recorded in two extents. The first
>   extent might consist of five contiguous clusters, the other of the
>   remaining 25 clusters.

If we use these terms, you file has 4 extents that include 11 clusters.

The utility `contig` therefore use non-standard terminology, employing
the term "fragments" for "extents", and the `-v` option just lists the clusters.

If you wish more precise wording, use the command:

```
fsutil file queryextents "C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\pp.big"
```

This built-in Windows command will use the Windows terms of "Clusters", "VCN"
and "LCN".

Reference : [Fsutil file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-file).

---

Wikipedia
[Extent (file systems)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extent_(file_systems))
explains more:

> An extent is a contiguous area of storage reserved for a file in a file system, represented as a range of block numbers, or tracks on Count key data devices. A file can consist of zero or more extents; one file fragment requires one extent. The direct benefit is in storing each range compactly as two numbers, instead of canonically storing every block number in the range.[1] Also, extent allocation results in less file fragmentation.

The question remains why the extents are not all of the same size,
even when they are contiguous on the disk. Or phrased differently,
why are not all contiguous clusters contained in one extent.
Extent sizes also seem to be rather random in length.

As I couldn't find any documentation on the subject, I can only theorize
that this depends on the driver and the workload on the computer, which is why the size is random.

As Windows is obliged to regularly flush out the file's metadata to the disk
Master File Table (MFT), my theory is that every time a flush is done,
a new data run (extent) is added to the file.

The size of the data run would then depend on how much data the driver
has written to the file on the disk in the elapsed time segment.
This would depend on factors such as total computer workload,
location on the disk of the data and the time it took to seek to it,
and many other factors.

I cannot point to any documentation on the subject, since I didn't find
any, but this theory does explain the posted findings.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about fsutil file queryextents. I updated the question with those numbers.

Comment: Note that the file is much larger than 11 clusters.

Comment: It has 11 data runs (extents), each composed of several clusters. I have extended my answer, although with a theory.

Comment: Do you consider your question as answered?

Comment: Your theory is possible, but hard to confirm

Comment: Seems very plausible to me, as without writing the file extension the written data will be lost if the computer fails, and such failure will result in disk sectors that are neither allocated nor free that will need to be fixed using chkdsk. The only way to verify it is to examine the source code of the disk driver, to which I have no access.